# Add reference to variable within other variable from batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables

I am trying to add an environment variable to my PATH from a batch file, but I would like to add it "by reference".

Right now I have:

```
setx VAR1 "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\MyDir"
setx PATH "%%VAR1%%;%PATH%"
```

**Problem 1:**

This creates the VAR1 in my environment variables but it is not known yet before the end of the script so my PATH variable ends up being `";C:/rest_of_my_path_variable"` (begin with an semi colon, but nothing added before).

**Problem 2:**

I would like my PATH variable to be `"%VAR1%;C:/rest_of_my_path_variable"` and not `"C:\Users\Pierre\MyDir;C:\rest_of_my_path_variable"` after this script, so that if VAR1 is modified later from any origin, the correct directory would still be in the PATH

I am a batch newbie just trying to automate some stuff on my win10 PC.

Any idea?

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window, type `Call /?`, press the 'ENTER' key, and read what the command does. Then get rid of it, because it isn't correct or required.

Comment: `SetX`, modifies the environment outside of that which is currently loaded. You will not see the changes until your restart the environment, i.e. a new `cmd.exe` instance.

Comment: @Compo do you have an alternative suggestion?

Comment: Yes, don't use `SetX` for changes to the current environment! If you need those variables to be defined for all future environments, there's nothing to stop you from defining them using `Set` to handle the current environment, and `SetX` for the future ones. Are you sure that you really need an environment variable for ever? I've got to be honest, I have never defined any user or system variable outside of the current environment, since `Windows 2000`, and I have never been in the situation where I have regretted not doing so.